# How to exclude file or folder from build task in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, csproj

I have vs solution which contains multiple projects,
And im now configuring CI/CD pipeline for the solution in azure.

There is one project i dont want to be include in release.

Im trying to remove that project in restore and build tasks.

[image]

But still it included in restore and build.

if anyone has an idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested on my side using build task, the exclude pattern is working as expected, please check the following sample and compare with yours:

Task:

[image]

Log:

[image]